# Shipping rate issue in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have used `opencart version : 2.0.1.1` and have defined below shipping rates based on weight,

```
800:40.00,1250:60.00,1700:80.00,2200:100.00,2700:120.00,999999:40.00
```

But in checkout/cart page prices are calculating correctly till `2200 grams` according to the definition  but if it exceeds more than `2200 grams` till `2700 grams`  it is showing wrong shipping price like for `2300 grams -> 276` instead of `120`. How we can resolve it.

Comment: is it 2700:120.00,999999:40.00 OR 2700:120.00,999999:400.00

Comment: 2700:120.00,999999:40.00 because after 2700 gms we are charging 40 rs per 1000 gms.

Comment: ok.. See if setting currency rate is set as 1.0000, weight is set as gram in store settings

Comment: @DrManishJoshi yes

Comment: as decimal paisa unit is 00, try 800:40,1250:60,1700:80,2200:100,2700:120,999999:40

Comment: It is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139823/discussion-between-mohan-and-dr-manish-joshi).